# Weblogic 12c deploy

Tags: java, weblogic12c

I'm trying to migrate my application from Tomcat to Weblogic 12.2.1.3.0. I'm able to deploy the application without error but I have a runtime error related to persistence provider. This is the stacktrace:

```
javax.validation.ValidationException: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isCascadeRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1275)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateCascadedConstraints(ValidatorImpl.java:472)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:322)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:139)
at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:194)
at eu.inn.webra.webflow.validators.AbstractValidator.validate(AbstractValidator.java:33)
at eu.inn.webra.webflow.validators.RaFormsValidator.validate(RaFormsValidator.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.FormAction.invokeValidatorMethod(FormAction.java:719)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.FormAction.doValidate(FormAction.java:834)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.FormAction.bindAndValidate(FormAction.java:491)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.DispatchMethodInvoker.invoke(DispatchMethodInvoker.java:98)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.MultiAction.doExecute(MultiAction.java:123)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.EvaluateAction.doExecute(EvaluateAction.java:77)
at org.springframework.webflow.action.AbstractAction.execute(AbstractAction.java:188)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.AnnotatedAction.execute(AnnotatedAction.java:145)
at org.springframework.webflow.execution.ActionExecutor.execute(ActionExecutor.java:51)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.ActionTransitionCriteria.test(ActionTransitionCriteria.java:82)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.support.TransitionCriteriaChain.test(TransitionCriteriaChain.java:71)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.canExecute(Transition.java:195)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Transition.execute(Transition.java:211)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.execute(FlowExecutionImpl.java:393)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.execute(RequestControlContextImpl.java:214)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.TransitionableState.handleEvent(TransitionableState.java:119)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.handleEvent(Flow.java:555)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.handleEvent(FlowExecutionImpl.java:388)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.RequestControlContextImpl.handleEvent(RequestControlContextImpl.java:210)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.handleEvent(ViewState.java:232)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.ViewState.resume(ViewState.java:196)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.Flow.resume(Flow.java:545)
at org.springframework.webflow.engine.impl.FlowExecutionImpl.resume(FlowExecutionImpl.java:258)
at org.springframework.webflow.executor.FlowExecutorImpl.resumeExecution(FlowExecutorImpl.java:169)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter.handle(FlowHandlerAdapter.java:183)
at org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowController.handleRequest(FlowController.java:174)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:286)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:260)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:137)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:350)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at eu.inn.webra.security.RaUrlCheckFilterBean.doFilter(RaUrlCheckFilterBean.java:52)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.java:94)
at eu.inn.webra.security.X509AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(X509AuthenticationFilter.java:41)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:125)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter.doFilter(ChannelProcessingFilter.java:144)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3701)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3667)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:197)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2443)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2291)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2269)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.runInternal(ServletRequestImpl.java:1703)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1663)
at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:272)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:92)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:61)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:131)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.isReachable(SingleThreadCachedTraversableResolver.java:46)
at org.hibernate.validator.engine.ValidatorImpl.isCascadeRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1266)
```

I googled for solutions before writing a question here and it seems that weblogic is trying to load `org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider` instead of the hibernate provider I'm using. A common solution is to define preference package into weblogic-application.xml:

```
<prefer-application-packages>
    <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.validation.spi.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
    <package-name>javax.persistence.spi.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</package-name>
    <package-name>org.opensaml.*</package-name>
    <package-name>net.sf.*</package-name>
</prefer-application-packages>
```

Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems a problem related to the ServiceProvider found by the ServiceLoader.
You can force the first resolution telling Weblogic to prefer your resources (and resources into your dependent jars)

Add this to your weblogic.xml (inside /WEB-INF/weblogic.xml):

```
<prefer-application-resources>
    <resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider</resource-name>
</prefer-application-resources
```